# iText 7 pdfSweep and JPX encoded composite image (MRC compressed PDF)

Tags: pdf, itext, redaction

I have a MRC compressed PDF (images are JPX encoded) which I can not get redacted with iText 7 pdfSweep as the ImageReadException is thrown.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Can't parse this format.
at org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getImageParser(Imaging.java:731)
at org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getImageInfo(Imaging.java:703)
at org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getImageInfo(Imaging.java:637)
at com.itextpdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpFilter.processImage(PdfCleanUpFilter.java:343)
... 13 more
```

Do you know any workaround or solution for this issue? An obvious workaround would be to replace the jp2 (jpx) in the PDF with some other image format and perform the redaction on this modified PDF, however, in this case the benefits of MRC compression are lost, not to mention the overall speed of such conversion and then redaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(iText developer here)

As you can see, iText uses `org.apache.commons` to handle the images.
In the past we have had some problems with known bugs in this external library.
A possible solution is to fork the `org.apache.commons` project, implement a fix, and submit your pull request.

This way, everyone benefits, and the change would automatically be included in `iText` as well.

Of course, should you be a paying customer, then reporting this problem through the iText support board might trigger us to do the pull request instead.

As for a workaround, I think you've already suggest the appropriate idea.

- process all images
- convert them to a different format (if needed)
- feed the modified document into `pdfSweep`

**More detailed (step 1 and 2)**

using IEventListener you can obtain the underlying `BufferedImage` of a given resource, and you can then use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ImageIO` to re-encode your image into standard jpg or png. You can then use `iText` to change the dictionary entry for this particular resource.

Comment: Any code sample available for this work around?